# Dependencies in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I have two components. I pass `handleCurrentAudioInputDeviceLabel` to Publisher.js where
I `setCurrentAudioInputDeviceLabel`. You can see that I am missing the dependency
`setCurrentAudioInputDeviceLabel` in useEffect. However, as soon I add it my component starts to re-render more often.

I thought about `useCallback`, but once I tried that, my linter says I have to add more than just `currentAudioInputDeviceLabel`.

VideoMeeting.js

```
const handleCurrentAudioInputDeviceLabel = (currentAudioInputDeviceLabel) => {
  setCurrentAudioInputDeviceLabel(currentAudioInputDeviceLabel);
};

<Publisher
  setCurrentAudioInputDeviceLabel={
    handleCurrentAudioInputDeviceLabel
  }
/>
```

Publisher.js

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Prevent to set audio source before publisher exists
  if (!publisherRef.current) {
      return;
  }

  const handleError = (error) =>
      onError(error, INITIATOR_AUDIO_DEVICE_PUBLISHER);

  publisherRef.current
      .setAudioSource(currentAudioInputDevice.deviceId)
      .then(() => {
      setCurrentAudioInputDeviceLabel(currentAudioInputDevice.label);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
      handleError(error);
      });
}, [currentAudioInputDevice, onError]);
```

Comment: Where is `onError()` defined?

Comment: [How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook/55854902#55854902) should help you

Comment: You can use useCallback like`const handleCurrentAudioInputDeviceLabel = useCallback((currentAudioInputDeviceLabel) => {
  setCurrentAudioInputDeviceLabel(currentAudioInputDeviceLabel);
},[setCurrentAudioInputDeviceLabel]);` and then add `setCurrentAudioInputDeviceLabel` as a dependency to useEffect in child. However if you are absolute sure about what you want, you can disable the warning